# Python-filtering though multiple files based on the contents of another file

Tags: python, loops, filtering

I'm a Python newbie and have run into a problem that I can't find an answer for anywhere.

I'm trying to write code to filter a set of files based on another file.  The files are arrays with multiple rows and columns.  What I would like is to remove rows from the data files that match rows in the filter file for certain columns.

The code is:

```
paths = ('filepaths.txt')#file that has filepaths to open
filter_file = ('filter.txt')#file of items to filter
filtered = open('filtered.txt','w') #output file

filtering = open(filter_file, 'r').readlines()
for f in filtering:
    filt = f.rstrip().split('\t')

files = open(paths).read().splitlines()
for file in files:
    try:
        lines = open(file,'r').readlines()
        for l in lines:
            data = l.rstrip().split('\t')

        a = [data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]] #data columns to match
        b= [filt[0], filt[1], filt[2], filt[3], filt[4]] #filter columns to match

        for i,j in zip(a,b): #loop through two lists to filter
            if i != j:
                matches = '\t'.join(data)
                print (matches)
                filtered.write(matches + '\n')
filtered.close()
```

The code executes, but doesn't work as I want.  What I get back is the last row of each file, repeated 5 times.

Clearly, I am missing something.  I'm not sure if zip is the right function to use, or if something else would be better.  I'd appreciate any advice.

Edit:

Sample input for filter:

```
HSPG2   22161380    22161380    G   A
PPTC7   110974744   110974744   G   C
OR1S2   57971546    57971546    A   C
```

Sample input for files to filter (extra columns left off):

```
TKTL1   8277    broad.mit.edu   37  X   153558089   153558089   +   3'UTR   SNP G   C   C
MPP1    4354    broad.mit.edu   37  X   154014502   154014502   +   Silent  SNP G   A   A
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
```

Sample output (extra columns left off):

```
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
BRCC3   79184   broad.mit.edu   37  X   154306908   154306908   +   Silent  SNP A   T   T
```

Comment: Can we have some sample input, a sample output and the output you are getting?

Comment: Could you post an example of the input files?

Comment: Part of your problem is with your `for f in filtering` and `for l in lines` loops - those read every line of the files before continuing to the stuff that happens after the list. Is the filter matching supposed to work line by line? EG, line 20 in each data file gets checked against line 20 of the filter file?

Comment: Peter, I want the all the rows in the files to be filtered to be filtered against all the rows row in the filter file.  There is no linkage of specific rows to be matched.

Comment: So it should remove rows that match any of the filter rows?

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to start with some simple changes, then show how you can use built in tools like Python's `csv` library and the `any` function to simplify the code.

Here's a version that cleans things up a little, and uses the correct logic, but doesn't introduce too many new language features. The main new things it uses are the `with` statement (which automatically closes the files when exited) and iterating directly over a file rather than using `readlines`:

```
paths = ('filepaths.txt')#file that has filepaths to open
filter_file = ('filter.txt')#file of items to filter
with open(filter_file, 'r') as filter_source:
    filters = []
    for line in filter_source:
        filters.append(line.rstrip().split('\t'))
with open(paths, 'r') as filename_source:
    filenames = []
    for line in filename_source:
        filenames.append(line.rstrip())
with open('filtered.txt','w') as filtered:
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,'r') as datafile:
            for line in datafile:
                data = l.rstrip().split('\t')
                a = [data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]] #data columns to match
                for filter in filters:
                    matched = True
                    for i,j in zip(a,filter):
                        if i != j:
                            matched = False
                            break
                    if matched:
                         # the data row matched a filter, stop checking for others
                         break
                if not matched:
                    filtered.write(line)
```

One thing we do several times there is use a for loop to build up a list. There's a more concise expression that does the same thing called a list comprehension. So using that, we'd have:

```
with open(filter_file, 'r') as filter_source:
    filters = [line.rstrip().split('\t') for line in filter_source]
with open(paths, 'r') as filename_source:
    filenames = [line.rstrip() for line in filename_source]
```

But Python also has a useful `csv` library that can take care of reading the tab delimited format:

```
import csv

with open(filter_file, 'rb') as filter_source:
    filter_reader = csv.reader(filter_source, delimiter='\t')
    filters = list(filter_reader)
```

When you iterate over it, it returns lists of the fields as separated by the delimiter character. Note that I opened it in `b` mode; whether that makes a difference or not depends on your platform, but if it does the csv docs note that it's required.

You could use it similarly for the data files, and optionally even to write your filtered output using the `writer` class.

Finally, the `any` and `all` builtins take iterables and return `True` if any or all of the contents of the iterables evaluate to `True`. You can use those to drop the nested for loop, using a generator expression - this is a construct similar to a list comprehension except that it's lazily evaluated, which is nice because `any` and `all` will shortcircuit. So here's a way to write this:

```
def match(dataline, filter):
    return all(i==j for (i, j) in zip(dataline, filter))
```

In this particular case I'm not getting much out of the shortcircuiting, because I'm using `zip` to build an actual list of tuples. But for such short lists it's fine, and `zip` outperforms `itertools.zip` (the lazy evaluating version) on lists that are already in memory.

Then you can use `any` to concisely compare the row to all your filters, shortcircuiting as soon as one matches:

```
a = [data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]]
if not any(match(a, filter) for filter in filters):
    filtered.write(line)
```

Except that this is still overkill. The `match` function is enforcing that all elements in its two inputs must be equal, but if you test whether two lists are equal that's part of what Python does automatically. The `match` function as I wrote it will allow lists of unequal length to match as long as the starting elements of the longer list all match the shorter list, while Python list equality does not, but that's not an issue here. So this would also work:

```
a = [data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]]
if not any (a==filter for filter in filters):
    filtered.write(line)
```

Or, if longer than normal filters are something you might want to tolerate:

```
if not any (a==filter[:5] for filter in filters):
```

The non-slicing version can also be written with direct list membership testing:

```
if a not in filters:
    filtered.write(line)
```

Also, as Blckknght points out Python has a better way to quickly test whether something like a line matches any of a number of patterns - the `set` datatype, which uses constant time lookups. Lists, like those returned by the `csv` library or by `split`, can't be the members of a set - but tuples can, as long as the members of the tuples are themselves hashable. So if you convert your filters and your data line subsets into tuples, you can maintain a set instead of a list and check it even faster. To do that, you have to convert each filter to a tuple:

```
filters = set(tuple(filter) for filter in filter_reader)
```

Then, define `a` as a tuple:

```
a = (data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11])
if a not in filters:
    filtered.write(line)
```

If you're using a `csv.writer` instance to write the output, you could even consolidate it further using the `writerows` method and a generator expression:

```
filtered_writer.writerows(data for data in data_reader if (data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]) not in filters)
```

So wrapping it all up, I would do this like this:

```
import csv

paths = ('filepaths.txt') #file that has filepaths to open
filter_file = ('filter.txt') #file of items to filter
with open(filter_file, 'rb') as filter_source:
    filters = set(tuple(filter) for filter in csv.reader(filter_source, delimiter='\t'))
with open(paths, 'r') as filename_source:
    filenames = [line.rstrip() for line in filename_source]
with open('filtered.txt','wb') as filtered:
    filtered_writer = csv.writer(filtered, delimiter='\t')
    for filename in filenames:
        with open(filename,'rb') as datafile:
            data_reader = csv.reader(datafile, delimiter='\t')
            filtered_writer.writerows(data for data in data_reader if (data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]) not in filters)
```

Comment: You could probably get a substantial performance boost (and a little code simplification) if you used a `set` of `tuple`s for the filters and then just tested a tuple with the key values from each line of the other files for membership in the set. `filters = set(tuple(line[:5]) for line in filter_source)` and later `a = (data[0], data[5], data[6], data[10], data[11]); if a not in filters: ...`

Comment: Good idea - how substantial a boost it is will depend on the number of filters, but it'll definitely be better. Even a version that just checks `any(a == filter for filter in filters)` would be clearer.

Comment: Peter, thanks for this incredibly detailed and informative response.  This is really helpful.  I think I understand the concepts of the changes you introduced, and why this makes the code better.  I seem to be running into a problem, however.  When I try either version of the code, I end up with a "list index out of range" error on the line where a=[data[0],…] is.  Any thoughts on why this is occurring?  Thanks again for the fantastic response.

Comment: That would happen if `data` doesn't have at least 12 elements when split. If that's expected, you can protect against it by checking `len(data)` before assigning `a`.

Comment: @PeterDeGlopper When I try `print (len(data))`, I get 92, so I don't think it's an issue of insufficient length.  I did notice something though; trying `print (data[5])` calls the `list index out of range` error, but trying `print(data[5:6])` pulls out the 6th column.  So when I rewrote the expression to `print (data[0:1], data[5:6], data[6:7], data[10:11], data[11:12])`, I seem to get the columns I want without the error.  Do you know why this works?

Comment: Slicing like that won't raise an `IndexError` if you run off the end of the list, but it will return a list rather than the contents of the list - `data[0:1]` is different from `data[0]`. That said, that's peculiar - what do you get for `type(data)`?

Comment: I get `<class 'list'>`

Comment: Hmm. It really shouldn't be possible for a list to raise `IndexError` when accessing an index below its length. I am at a loss to explain it based on what I've seen here - it must be the result of something else wrong. Just to confirm, you're using `print` with parens because you're on Python 3, right? That wouldn't be a fatal error if not, but it might confuse things a little.

Comment: Yes, I'm using Python 3.  If it helps, I don't get the error when I call data[0]; only when I ask for anything else in data.

Comment: Ah, I figured it out…my files have headers that have fewer elements, which is calling out the error.  Totally silly on my part.  I need to start reading from the third line, so I should try something like `with open(filename,'r') as datafile:
            line = line[2:]`, right?

Comment: If you have a header line, the usual patterns are either to read and ignore it (`headers = data_reader.next()`, then proceed with the usual processing if you're using the `csv` library, `headers_line = datafile.readline(), then proceed with the usual processing if you're not) or to use a `csv.DictReader` class and construct your comparable tuple for a given row from a dict representation rather than a list. You could also take a simpler path and either always or never write rows that are under the expected length.

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't really change the headers myself, as I am processing thousands of files that have been previously generated.  I also have 2 header lines.  I was able to get it to work by using the range/next functions.  Thanks again for your help on this topic.  The code is working great!

Answer (score 0):

When you create `filt`, you're creating one string variable and overwriting it multiple times. Try replacing

```
for f in filtering:
    filt = f.rstrip().split('\t')
```

with

```
filt = [f.rstrip().split('\t') for f in filtering]
```

Now `filt` is a list of lists, with each element representing one row. So for example, `filt[0]` will give you the first row, and `filt[2][3]` will give you the fourth column of the third row. You may have to modify the rest of your program to work correctly with this.

Comment: Thanks.  When I try that, I get the error- 'list' object has no attribute 'rstrip'.  I presume this is because strip can't be applied to lists?